# How long is the Google Business Profile Performance API latency for preparing the information(Data Freshness)?

Tags: java, google-my-business-api, google-business-profile-api

I am using this API [Business Profile Performance](https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/performance/rest/v1/locations/getDailyMetricsTimeSeries), and I see few documentation. Does anybody know how long it takes for Google to respond?
I see 48 to 72 hours delay.Is it happening for others, or something is wrong with my code?

For making the code shorter, suppose that the function ***initializeMyBusiness()*** is responsible for initialising the API via its Builder and also takes care of authentication.

***locationsList*** is a List of Strings including the location IDs' of the client.

```
 private enum PerformanceMetrics {
        BUSINESS_IMPRESSIONS_DESKTOP_MAPS,
        BUSINESS_IMPRESSIONS_DESKTOP_SEARCH,
        BUSINESS_IMPRESSIONS_MOBILE_MAPS , 
        BUSINESS_IMPRESSIONS_MOBILE_SEARCH,
        BUSINESS_CONVERSATIONS,
        BUSINESS_DIRECTION_REQUESTS, 
        CALL_CLICKS,
        WEBSITE_CLICKS
    }
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    business_profile_performance = initializeMyBusiness();

    locationsList.stream().forEach(u -> {

        for(PerformanceMetrics dailyMetric:PerformanceMetrics.values() ) {
            try {
                
                BusinessProfilePerformance.Locations.GetDailyMetricsTimeSeries metricReport =
                        business_profile_performance.locations().
                        getDailyMetricsTimeSeries(locationID).
                        setDailyMetric(dailyMetric.toString()).
                        setDailyRangeStartDateYear(Integer.valueOf("2022")).
                        setDailyRangeStartDateMonth(Integer.valueOf("12")).
                        setDailyRangeStartDateDay(Integer.valueOf("26")).

                        setDailyRangeEndDateYear(Integer.valueOf("2022")).
                        setDailyRangeEndDateMonth(Integer.valueOf("12")).
                        setDailyRangeEndDateDay(Integer.valueOf("27"));


                GetDailyMetricsTimeSeriesResponse response = metricReport.execute();
                if (!response.isEmpty()) {
                    System.out.println(" Response == " + response);
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }

        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working as expected, the data does not become stable before the 48 to 72 hours you are observing.