# How much delay has the Google Business Performance API to return the info fetchMultiDailyMetricsTimeSeries

Tags: java, google-my-business-api, google-my-business, google-business-profile-api, google-business-profile

I am having problems by the `Google Business Performance API` being late for more than 5 days to return the insights of my locations ( documentation here: [Google Business Performance](https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/performance/rest/v1/locations/fetchMultiDailyMetricsTimeSeries) ).
This was the same problem I have asked before [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74953430/how-long-is-the-google-business-profile-performance-api-latency-for-preparing-th).
I see it continues to change, I need to be sure about the values I read.
The code is

```
      private enum PerformanceMetrics {
            BUSINESS_IMPRESSIONS_DESKTOP_MAPS,
            BUSINESS_IMPRESSIONS_DESKTOP_SEARCH,
            BUSINESS_IMPRESSIONS_MOBILE_MAPS , 
            BUSINESS_IMPRESSIONS_MOBILE_SEARCH,
            BUSINESS_CONVERSATIONS,
            BUSINESS_DIRECTION_REQUESTS, 
            CALL_CLICKS,
            WEBSITE_CLICKS
        }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    
        business_profile_performance = initializeMyBusiness();
    
        locationsList.stream().forEach(u -> {
    
            for(PerformanceMetrics dailyMetric:PerformanceMetrics.values() ) {
                try {
                    
                    BusinessProfilePerformance.Locations.GetDailyMetricsTimeSeries metricReport =
                            business_profile_performance.locations().
                            getDailyMetricsTimeSeries(locationID).
                            setDailyMetric(dailyMetric.toString()).
                            setDailyRangeStartDateYear(Integer.valueOf("2022")).
                            setDailyRangeStartDateMonth(Integer.valueOf("12")).
                            setDailyRangeStartDateDay(Integer.valueOf("26")).
    
                            setDailyRangeEndDateYear(Integer.valueOf("2022")).
                            setDailyRangeEndDateMonth(Integer.valueOf("12")).
                            setDailyRangeEndDateDay(Integer.valueOf("27"));
    
    
                    GetDailyMetricsTimeSeriesResponse response = metricReport.execute();
                    if (!response.isEmpty()) {
                        System.out.println(" Response == " + response);
                    }
    
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println(e);
                }
    
            }
        });

}
```

Any Experience?
Thank you all.

Comment: I've had the same issues, with direction actions being especially delayed, sometimes up to 10 days. When I reach out to support they say this is expected behavior. My solution was to re-pull the last 14 days every run

Comment: @AndrewWalker: thank you for the response, my problem is that we have clients that they have more than 5000 stores, so the repetitive task is somehow time and resource consuming.